# AudioManager is introducing delay in the setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

I am trying to play sound on speaker even if headphones are on, BUT if there is music playing in background, I want the music to be played on headphones until the sound is played.

So I am taking the next steps:

- Before I play sound, I gain audioFocus so all the background music is
  stopped
- After audioFocus is gained, I set `MODE_COMMUNICATION` to the
  AudioManager, so the sound can be played on the speaker.
- After the sound ends, I abandonAudioFocus and set back `MODE_NORMAL` to
  `AudioManager`, so the background music can continue playing on the headphones.

The strange thing is that it depends from the device, on some device this is OK, ***but on Nexus 6P (Huawei) devices after setting the `MODE_COMMUNICATION` there is delay 3-4 seconds before the sound can be played. If I play the sound without the delay, it is not played neither to speaker nor to headphones.***

**THE QUESTION**

How can I know how much delay to set before the sound is played? Is there any listener that I can attach, so can notify me that after setting `MODE_COMMUNICATION` the sound is ready to be played?

I don't want to set delay even if it is not necessary!

The solution is not setting the mode into the constructor of the class(to skip the delay), because I need the sound to be played on speaker in the specific moment!

P.S: I am playing the sound with `AudioTrack`, but I tried with `MediaPlayer` as well (setting `setAudioStreamType(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)`), but no success, the delay is still there!

So any suggestions?

Comment: i have a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962412/androids-audiomanager-setmodeaudiomanager-mode-in-communication-causes-playou did you find some solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this post, what worked for me was calling `AudioManager.setMode()` and then recreating my `MediaPlayer` (via constructor, not `create()`) and using `setAudioAttributes()` to change the output source.

Kotlin snippet:

```
fun switchOutput(inCommunication: Boolean) {

    //STEP 1: Change the AudioManager's audio mode
    if(inCommunication) {
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
        audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
    } else {
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
        audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
    }

    //STEP 2: Recreate the MediaPlayer
    if (player != null) {
        try {
            player?.stop()
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        } finally {
            player?.reset()
            player?.release()
            player = null
        }
    }

    player = MediaPlayer()
    try {
        val streamType =
                if (inCommunication) AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL
                else AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
        player?.setDataSource(dataSource)
        player?.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setLegacyStreamType(streamType)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build())
        player?.prepare()
        player?.start()
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {}
}
```

Hope this helps :)

P.S. Notice I've used `MODE_IN_CALL` instead of `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`

Comment: your solution required API level 21 at least.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib it's been a long long time since I developed an app with a minSDK lower than 21 >.<

Comment: I create issue about this to google tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204709351.  The issue includes a simple app that can be used to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If device supports API level 31 or greater, it is possible to use AudioManager.OnModeChangedListener to detect when audio mode changes to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, something like this:

```
val am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
var audioModeChangedListener = AudioManager.OnModeChangedListener { mode ->
  if (mode == AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio mode changed to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION")
    if (audioModeChangedListener != null) {
      am.removeOnModeChangedListener(audioModeChangedListener!!)
      audioModeChangedListener = null
    }
    // start playing
  }
}
am.addOnModeChangedListener(mainExecutor, audioModeChangedListener!!)
Log.d(TAG, "Setting audio mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION")
am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
```